# Do I have to enter email address to other communities also?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, login, openid, email

I already entered my email address while signing up at this site. But other sites still showing blank space under email address.

[image]

Do I have to ignore and also tell me what will happen if I don't enter my email ID at travel stackexchange or any other community?